# How to add $ sign to Default Code in Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm setting up my default code which include the following for it to work with WINCVS:

```
CVS  
/*  
     $Id  
     $Log  
*/  
//Insert code here
```

However, when I go to create a new file, the dollar sign disappear leaving me with:

```
CVS
/*
     Id
     Log
*/
//Insert code here
```

What do I have to append to my Default Code so that the "$" sign stays?

I'm running c++ on code blocks 16.01 on windows 10.

Comment: Wow. CVS. Now that's a blast from the past, and I feel old still using SVN.

Comment: Maybe try `$$` or `\$`?

Comment: Thanks @HolyBlackCat $$ worked!